# Can't connect to github via ssh; Permission denied (public key)

Tags: git, macos, ubuntu, github, ssh

I'm trying to logon to github via ssh but it fails. I've checked the github troubleshooting page to no avail. I've followed the guide on how to connect via ssh step by step on two separate computers. I've tried specifying the path to id_rsa but it gives the same response. The output I receive is the following:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/disid/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/disid/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/disid/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/disid/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/disid/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/disid/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/disid/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/disid/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/disid/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/disid/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/disid/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/disid/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/disid/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

On the other computer which is a mac it also said `key_load_public:No such file or directory` after each identity file check. So perhaps ssh is not completely set up on my computers. What is the problem?

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's the same in Ubuntu. So the problem might be related to all unix based OS's.

Comment: Whatever.  It doesn't become a programming question just because the host is github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

In order to be on the safe side add the new keys to your ssh agent.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

#### How to add ssh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Comment: Thanks. Tried this on a different user and it works. The problem arises when I try on a user generated by my school. Don't know why this is but will consult with my school instead.